# Triggering clicks in GTM using virtual view and counting them as a event goal in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am having trouble tracking a click using Google Tag Manager.

I have set up a click event, and a click trigger. The click trigger's conditions are:     `Click Class`- Equals - next-step`

Screenshots: 
[This is how I created the tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn3tl.png) [This is the trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2JHA.png)

Currently the problem is that the trigger is not firing.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the HTML for the click you are trying to track?

Comment: Hi, here is the link for screenshot : http://imgur.com/a/pY5tV

Comment: You will need to do some more debugging. When you are in GTM debug more and you click the element you want to track, what values do you see during the "gtm.click" event for the variable "Click Classes"? If you don't see `next-step`, then your tag will not fire.

Comment: The main reason why trigger was not fired because of 2 different classes we had on the text div container and the box container, as sdhaus has declared here.  We have added unique class name to both div and its working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is occuring because there are two different elements that are able to be clicked: next-step and ng-binding.

If you click on the text itself, it will have the class ng-binding.

[image]

Whereas, if you click anywhere else on the button, it will have the class next-step.

[image]

Because your ng-binding is not a unique attribute to fire this event from, I would create a DataLayer variable (lets call it Parent Node Class) with the following selector:

```
gtm.element.parentNode.className
```

This will return the className of the parent node, reletive to the element clicked. This means that users clicking on ng-binding will have the Parent Node Class of 'next-step'.

Using this, you can have two triggers for your tag.

```
1) Click Classes equals next-step

2) Parent Node Class equals next-step
```

Because triggers work with an 'or' condition, this means that if either of these results are satisfied, then it will fire the tag.

Comment: Hi, sdhaus, You are genius! Since I am not familiar with DataLayer  yet, our solution was following. We added unique class name to both div container. Here is the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/73PUO and beside as in trigger we changed class name "equals" to "contains", because on case of equals it was not triggered.